# UITableView ObjectAtIndex

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'm developing an iPhone app that is a tabViewController with one of the tabs including a tableView. Objects in the table can be touched to go to a splash screen with information for that specific object.

Here's how I set up the array tableView:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 //each table view cell has its own identifier. 
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier"; 
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; 

 if (cell == nil)
 {
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
 }

 NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 

 cell.textLabel.text = [sitesArray objectAtIndex:row];
 cell.imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:row];

 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

 return cell; 
}

    - (void)viewDidLoad {

  NSArray *pageHolder = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"CSLP", @"NSLS", @"LSPA", @"SIOP", @"Transfer", nil];
  self.pages = pageHolder;
  [pageHolder release]; 

  NSArray *sites = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"CSLP", @"NSLS", @"LSPA", @"SIOP", @"Transfer Vision Program ", nil];
 self.sitesArray = sites; 

 UIImage *cslp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CSLP LOGO.png"]; 
 UIImage *nsls = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NSLS LOGO.png"]; 
 UIImage *lspa = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LSPA LOGO.png"]; 
 UIImage *siop = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SIOP LOGO.png"]; 
 UIImage *transfer = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TRANSFER LOGO.png"]; 
 NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: cslp, nsls, lspa, siop, transfer, nil]; 
 [sites release]; 
 self.imagesArray = images; 

 UIButton* modalViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 [modalViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(modalViewAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 UIBarButtonItem *modalBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:modalViewButton];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = modalBarButtonItem;
 [modalBarButtonItem release];

 [self.table reloadData];
}
```

And here's my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
 NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

 NSMutableDictionary *rowData = [table objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 UIViewController *targetViewController = [rowData objectForKey:kViewControllerKey];
 if (!targetViewController)
 {
        // The view controller has not been created yet, create it and set it to our menuList array
        NSString *viewControllerName = [[pages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAppendingString:@"ViewController"];
        targetViewController = [[NSClassFromString(viewControllerName) alloc] initWithNibName:viewControllerName bundle:nil];
        [rowData setValue:targetViewController forKey:kViewControllerKey];
  [targetViewController release];
    }

 SSARC_App_2AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
 [delegate.orgsNavigationController pushNavigationItem:targetViewController animated:YES];

 [delegate release];
 }
```

The application crashes at the first call to objectAtIndex in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. The console states:

> 010-11-22 12:50:17.113 SSARC App
>   2[43470:207] -[UITableView
>   objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x601e800 2010-11-22
>   12:50:17.116 SSARC App 2[43470:207]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UITableView objectAtIndex:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x601e800'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:

Now, I have a warning that says "UITableView may be unresponsive to ObjectAtIndex". I'm assuming this is the main issue here, however I'm unsure how to solve it. Interestingly enough I've searched for this issue everywhere, and cannot find it anywhere, so I'm curious to know if anyone has run into this problem and how to solve it. Any advice would be great. Let me know if you need more information.

---

I've been doing some coding on my own and I've gotten it to compile without any errors or warnings, but it still crashes. Currently this is what I have:

```
NSMutableDictionary *rowData = [self.menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIViewController *targetViewController = [rowData objectForKey:kViewControllerKey];
if (!targetViewController)
{
    // The view controller has not been created yet, create it and set it to our menuList array

NSString *viewControllerName = [[pages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAppendingString:@"ViewController"];

targetViewController = [[NSClassFromString(viewControllerName) alloc] init];//WithNibName:viewControllerName bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"targetViewController: %@", targetViewController); 

    [rowData setValue:targetViewController forKey:kViewControllerKey];
    [targetViewController release];
}


SSARC_App_2AppDelegate *delegate = (SSARC_App_2AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
[[delegate orgsNavigationController] pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];

[delegate release]; 

delegate = nil;
```

The issue that the debugger reports is that 'viewControllerName' is 'Out of Scope'. I don't really understand what that means because when I use NSLog, viewControllerName is initialized. Does that mean it cannot find the class I'm referring to? Please let me know.

Comment: Can u show the property declaration of `sitesArray`

Comment: Can u show the property declaration of `sitesArray`, `imagesArray` and `pages`

Comment: Hello! The property definition of those arrays are as follows: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *pages;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *imagesArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sitesArray;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `table` is your `UITableView`, the call to `[table objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is completely nonsensical. It looks to me like you should be calling `[pages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` instead.

Comment: Thank you for that information. After changing the call to pages instead of table I still crash, but it says 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x708c' now.

Comment: My viewDidLoad also has been changed to:  if (!pages)
 {
  pages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"CSLP", @"NSLS", @"LSPA", @"SIOP", @"Transfer", nil];
    }
 //menuLIst == sitesArray
    for (NSString *pageName in pages)
 {
  [self.sitesArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          NSLocalizedString([pageName stringByAppendingString:@"Title"], @""), kTitleKey,
          NSLocalizedString([pageName stringByAppendingString:@"Explain"], @""), kDetailKey,
          nil]];
 }
In place of the old initialization for pages.

Answer (score 0):

**objectAtIndex** should be called either for NSMutableArray Or NSArray. You cann't call it from UITableview Or CFDictionary Or CFString. So if you gets any warning Solve the warning first and then proceed further.